# Endpoints configuration not updated.Communication failure with app

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

```
 Beginning interaction for module default...
0% Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\SSB469~1.SS-\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg1081844926449198215.tmp'
5% Scanning for jsp files.
20% Scanning files on local disk.
25% Initiating update.
28% Cloning 2 static files.
31% Cloning 36 application files.
40% Uploading 0 files.
52% Initializing precompilation...
90% Deploying new version.
95% Will check again in 1 seconds.
98% Will check again in 2 seconds.
99% Will check again in 4 seconds.
99% Will check again in 8 seconds.
99% Will check again in 16 seconds.
99% Will check again in 32 seconds.
99% Will check again in 60 seconds.
99% Will check again in 60 seconds.
99% Will check again in 60 seconds.
99% Will check again in 60 seconds.
99% Will check again in 60 seconds.
99% Will check again in 60 seconds.
99% Will check again in 60 seconds.

  com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload checkEndpointsServingStatusResult
    SEVERE: Endpoints configuration not updated.  Communication failure with app.
```

I keep on getting this error while deploying my backend endpoints to app engine.Everything works for few deployments and than suddenly on a nth deployment its their and stops me from deploying.